# can we create map with two locations addresses without center of map

Tags: google-maps

I need to create a Google Map with the two addresses of the route that I want to display on Google Map. I do not have the center. Does Google Map calculate the center based on the two addresses or it is mandatory to specify a center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any dummy location while initializing the map. If you know the coordinates of the two points you can use LatLngBounds to ensure that both points are shown on the map.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
bounds.extend(latlng1);
bounds.extend(latlng2);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

This code takes both the points and ensures that the google map viewport includes both these points while displaying. Hence you do not need to calculate the center.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Gooogle Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), that centers the map to show the entire route by default.

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

    function initialize() {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var mapOptions = {};
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute() {
      var start = 'Chicago, IL';
      var end = 'St Louis, MO';
      var request = {
          origin:start,
          destination:end,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directions2.html)